# If-Else statement issue in r

Tags: r, dataframe, if-statement

I am trying to create a function that will return "positive" or "negative" from three different columns in a data frame.

This is my code:

```
BeforeDep <- BeforeWar_HaveDepression
BeforeAnx <- BeforeWar_HaveAnxiety
BeforePTSD <- BeforeWar_HavePTSD

BeforeWar_MentalHealth <- function(BeforeDep, BeforeAnx, BeforePTSD)
  if (BeforeDep == 1) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else if (BeforeAnx == 1) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else if (BeforePTSD == 1 ) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else {
    print ("Negative")
  }
```

However when I run this code, it doesn't work. What mistake am I making? Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Which is your error?

Comment: if you are running this on vectors, you'll need to use `ifelse`, which is vectorized.

Comment: `printt()`ing is different than `return()`ing. There's rarely a need to `print` inside a function - if you want to tell the user something, it's usually better to use `message()` or `warning()`. If you want to give them an R object (like the character string `"Negative"`), then use `return()`.

Answer (score 0):

did you call your function with the arguments? I tried your function and it works. See below

```
BeforeDep <- 1
BeforeAnx <- 1
BeforePTSD <- 1

BeforeWar_MentalHealth <- function(BeforeDep, BeforeAnx, BeforePTSD)
  if (BeforeDep == 1) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else if (BeforeAnx == 1) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else if (BeforePTSD == 1 ) {
    print ("Positive")
  } else {
    print ("Negative")
  }


# Calling the function
BeforeWar_MentalHealth(0,0,0)
```

Output :

```
> BeforeWar_MentalHealth(1,1,1)
[1] "Positive"
> BeforeWar_MentalHealth(0,1,1)
[1] "Positive"
> BeforeWar_MentalHealth(0,0,0)
[1] "Negative"
```